# PHP Global Namespace Not Working On Heroku

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, heroku, composer-php

so I've been migrating a legacy project to Heroku and been using Composer to manage dependencies, such as `aws/aws-sdk-php`.

Unfortunately, on Heroku, I get fatal errors like `Fatal error: Interface 'Countable' not found in /app/app/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/HandlerList.php on line 33` when I try and use them, but not locally.

The class definition looks like `class HandlerList implements \Countable` (from what I've read `\` is for global namespace).

If I manually edit it through bash on Heroku (`heroku run bash`) and remove the `\`, it seems to work: `class HandlerList implements Countable`.

Heroku is using PHP 5.6.20

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem with AWS-SDK. It does work properly on local, but not on Heroku. Have you figured out?